# SCI/other credible journals for low budget authors

Tags: publications, journals, authorship

I have done some work and I thought of publishing it. This is my first attempt to publish. After searching a lot, I found out that SCI indexed journals are good. But I am seeing publishing price at about $1500-$3100 which is absolutely impossible for me. (Just out of question). My work is on improvement in image processing, being specific, matrix encoding algorithms.

I am putting my question here after searching too much, so any hint would help. I am almost about $100-$150 budget. I don't understand how sharing info could be so costly. Is it not done as a service by scientists/Phd students collectively at some reasonable price ?

Its a baffling experience to me, specially this listed price on journal websites. In my country this amount means fortune.

Comment: Many journals charge subscription fees instead of publication charges.

Comment: Also see [Do Springer IEEE Elsevier charge a fee...](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18625/do-springer-ieee-elsevier-charge-a-fee-for-non-open-access-journals) - those publishers all have signal processing journals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many journals do not charge any publication fees at all.  For example, subscription journals often fall into this category, and in most fields there are plenty of subscription journals.  If all the journals you are finding charge fees, then I'd imagine you aren't searching broadly enough (although maybe publication fees are particularly common in your field).

Furthermore, journals that charge publication fees ought to give fee waivers to authors from developing countries.  Their web sites often explain the details, and if they don't you can write to them to ask before submission.  They might in principle say no, but it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: *If all the journals you are finding charge fees, then either you're in an unusual field or you aren't searching broadly enough*.  Is that just your impression, or are there some facts on this?

Comment: I don't have a citation handy, but I don't think it's a controversial or surprising assertion.  As of a few years ago, only a tiny fraction of articles were published in gold (=paid) OA journals (see http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3664).  This still leaves the possibility of page charges in subscription journals, but they are far from universal (and in any case don't fit the description of what the OP is finding).  I can imagine there are fields in which all mainstream journals charge fees, but I'd bet the only such fields are both very small and new, without a long history of journals.

Comment: Most, if not all, quality journals in my field (Geosciences) charge publication fees, and most are closed-access.  AGU (American Geophysical Union) journals charge fees [for publication](http://is.gd/mus08Q) and [for subscription](http://is.gd/hY1N9P).  EGU (European Geophysical Union) Copernicus open-access journals all charge publication fees.  AMS (American Meteorological Society) journals charge [page fees](http://is.gd/y9zkyY) and subscription fees.  Is my field unusual?  One (Japanese) journal I know of charged hundreds of dollar extra per colour page for an *online-only* publication.

Comment: Hmm, I hope it's unusual, since that seems like the worst of both worlds (although even there, half of all AGU journals have no fees for short papers).  But I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician : thanks for your answer. Its helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at PLOS ONE. See their description of their [Publication Charges](http://www.plosone.org/static/information). The journal has a good reputation, publishes research in all discliplines, has a reduced or waived fee for authors from low income countries, and a separate fee waiver program.